# jquery-ujs apparently handling event but result not visible on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

this block

```
<div id='travels' class='tableize'>
  <%= render @travels %>
</div>
```

is then sent off to render via `_travel.html.erb` partial the following form and result for each records of @travels

```
  <div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns text-right'>
    <%= form_with(model: travel, remote: true, data: {'js-travel-form' => true, method: :patch}, url: restriction_update_travels_path, data: {'js-travel-form' => true}) do |form| %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :id, value: travel.id %>
      <%= form.submit ' Change' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns' data-js-travelstatus=<%= travel.id %>>
    <% if travel.restricted %>
      <%= fa_icon('ban', class: 'fa-lg smaller warning') %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

The controller updates a status and sends off

```
@travel = Travel.find(params[:travel][:id])
if @travel.restricted.nil? || !@travel.restricted? 
  @travel.update_attributes(restricted: true)
else
  @travel.update_attributes(restricted: false)
end
if @travel.save
  render partial: 'travelstatus'
end
```

where `restriction_update.js.erb` generates the following js

```
$("#data-js-travelstatus").replaceWith("<%= j(render @travelstatus)  %>");
```

to render via `_travelstatus.html.erb`

```
<% if @travel.restricted %>
  good      <%= fa_icon('ban', class: 'fa-lg smaller warning') %>
<% end %>
```

The browser developer tool network console picks up the action and returns as a response

```
good
```

but

1. no further html as per the html.erb partial which is odd because if I replace the @travel instance variable with `travel` it returns the expected rails error papyrus
2. and the status situation is not refreshed (in either true of false mode)... not even the 'good' raw string.

rails 5.2.4 but invoking `jquery-ujs`

where has this gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```rb
$("#data-js-travelstatus").replaceWith("<%= j(render @travelstatus)  %>");
```

JavaScript can't find the node `#data-js-travestatus`, which you expect to be `<div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns' data-js-travelstatus=<%= travel.id %>>`. But there's no `id` attribute set on that `div`.

You could rewrite it as:

```rb
<div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns' id="<%= travel.id %>">
```

and

```rb
$("#<%= @travel.id %>").replaceWith("<%= j(render @travelstatus)  %>");
```

UPDATE: I missed this:

You are rendering `travelstatus`, which is wrong. You need to render `restriction_update`.

```rb
@travel = Travel.find(params[:travel][:id])
if @travel.restricted.nil? || !@travel.restricted? 
  @travel.update_attributes(restricted: true)
else
  @travel.update_attributes(restricted: false)
end
if @travel.save
  #render partial: 'travelstatus' <- this is wrong
  render partial 'restriction_update'
end
```

Comment: That did not work out.  The action is picked up, the browser dev network tool returns the same 'good' string...

Comment: renamed the partial.  Same network tool response of only the 'string' but nothing visible on the browser...

Comment: I see two problems: First, the response is incomplete (only `good`). Second, the div is not being updated. I'd fix the later first. So, is a div with the expected id being rendered? Is the selector used in `restriction_update` working in the browser console? Can you update the div by hand in the browser console? Is the partial being executed (add byebug in `restriction_update` to check `@travel.id` and `@travelstatus`). What's the value of `@travelstatus`, btw?

Comment: @travel.id returns a correct answer... but your hunch is correct, `@travelstatus` returns nil

Comment: I guess it should be `$("#<%= @travel.id %>").replaceWith("<%= j(render 'travelstatus') %>");`, the partial's name.